# (Native React)Cant get counter to work for both items individually in Native react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

im trying to get my counter to work for both my items individually, but each time i touch increase button on 1 item it increases for both of them
this what the app looks like [appimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd7Wv.jpg)

CounterApp.js file ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
class CounterApp extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Increase</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.counter}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.decreaseCounter()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Decrease</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />

<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter2()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Increase</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.counter}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.decreaseCounter2()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Decrease</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter,

    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
        decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
        increaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
        decreaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),

    }
}







export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(CounterApp)


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

app.js file //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import CounterApp from './src/CounterApp'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
/**
 * Store - holds our state - THERE IS ONLY ONE STATE 
 * Action - State can be modified using actions - SIMPLE OBJECTS 
 * Dispatcher - Action needs to be sent by someone - known as dispatching an action
 * Reducer - receives the action and modifies the state to give us a new state 
 *  - pure functions 
 *  - only mandatory argument is the 'type' 
 * Subscriber - listens for state change to update the ui  
 */
const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
            return { counter: state.counter + 1 }
        case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
            return { counter: state.counter - 1 }
    }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

class App extends Component {

    render() {




      return (





           <Provider store={store}>
                <CounterApp />

            </Provider>


        );
    }
}

export default App

// export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they both are mapping from the same source of props

instead of  :

```
increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
increaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
decreaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
```

you should have this structure :

```
increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
increaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER2' }),
decreaseCounter2: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER2' }),
```

next change this :

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
        return { counter: state.counter1 + 1 }
    case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
        return { counter: state.counter1 - 1 }
    case 'DECREASE_COUNTER2':
        return { counter: state.counter2 + 1 }
    case 'INCREASE_COUNTER2':
        return { counter: state.counter2 - 1 }
}
return state
}
```

next this :

```
const initialState = {
    counter1: 0,
    counter2: 0,
}
```

next assign specific prop to each counter :

```
return {
        counter1: state.counter1,
        counter2: state.counter2,
}


<Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.counter1}</Text>
<Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.counter2}</Text>
```

Comment: the number disappeared, this what i have  https://jsfiddle.net/xuzw9k4j/  ,  https://jsfiddle.net/uneL7jfr/

Comment: sorry i have edited my code at the mapStateToProps , change {counter , counter} to {counter1 , counter2}

Comment: it erases the number after i push the button, this my code https://jsfiddle.net/o07z8Lnj/  , https://jsfiddle.net/u3mrq15f/

Comment: just checked the code the problem is with const reducer pay attention to cases the last one , edit and fix the name and it will fix